# how to use an optgroup in a foreach?

Tags: php

In my select box I am trying to do this:

```
Maincategory name
   subcat
   subcat
   subcat
anothermain category
    subcat
    subcat
```

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
<select name="categories" class="form-control col-sm-12">
    <?php foreach(ProductModel::categories() as $category): ?>
      <option value="<?=System::escape($category->sub_category); ?>"><?=System::escape($category->sub_category); ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

I **don't** want to show the main cate name on all the sub cats like

```
maincate:subcat
maincate:subcat
maincate:subcat
```

This is my table:

[image]

How would I go about doing this? I cant do if there's 5 inside the foreach show cat name because I'll never have the same amount of subcats in each main cats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, before your for each loop, you could assign a variable to the current main category name (starting it as null), then check it every time you iterate to see if it matches the current entry's main category. If it doesn't, have it close the previous optgroup and open a new optgroup for the main category and then another for the current sub category. Then assign the variable to the current main category value and you should be good to go. You'd probably have it skip the close tag if the variable was undefined (i.e., the first time 'round).

Something like this:

So:

```
<select name="categories" class="form-control col-sm-12">
    <?php 
         $i = 0;
         $mainCatName = '';
         foreach(ProductModel::categories() as $category): 
         if($category->main_category != $mainCatName {
             $mainCatName = $category->main_category;
             if($i = 0) { ?>
                <optgroup label="<?php echo $category->main_category ?>">
             <?php } else {
                 </optgroup>
                 <optgroup label="<?php echo $category->main_category ?>">
             <?php }
         }
          ?>
      <option value="<?=System::escape($category->sub_category); ?>"><?=System::escape($category->sub_category); ?></option>
      <?php if($i = count(count(ProductModel::categories()) { ?>
         </optgroup>
      <?php } 
      $i++;?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: You would just want to make sure when you pull them out of the db you are sorting by main category.

Comment: Mind you you could probably do this more elegantly with a for loop.